# Basis of subgroups with full rank of free abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, integer-lattices, free-abelian-group

Let $A$ be a free abelian group of rank $k$ and $v_1,\dots,v_k$ be its basis.

Let $B \le A$ be a subgroup of $A$ of full rank. I want to construct a basis of $B$ from $v_1,\dots,v_k$. One way I can think of is the following:

Consider the projection $A \to A/B$ and for each $i$ the image $v_i+B$ are of finite order, say $n_i$. I don't have to show that

$$n_1 v_1 \dots n_k v_k$$

form a basis of $B$. It is clear that $n_1 v_1 \dots n_k v_k$ are $\mathbb Z$ independent and they are contained in $B$ but I don't see why any element in $A$ can be expressed by them.

If you have other ways to construct the basis so that the proof is easier, please let me know in the answer. I have seen a similar theorem before but I can't find any reference directly addressing what I want.

Comment: This is not in general a free basis of $B$. There is a standard result that says that you can choose the free basis of $A$ such that $B$ has a free basis of the form $\{n_iv_i : 1 \le i \le k \}$, but this is not true for an arbitrary free basis of $A$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you show me a reference of that general result? Or prove it directly? We are only looking at finite rank case I think proof is not too complicated...

Comment: @DerekHolt also are you sure my statement even fails in the case of finite rank free abelian? What is a counterexample?

Comment: Thm 10.21 of Rotman's Introduction to the Theory of Groups, 4th edition. Example: $k=2$, $B = \langle v_1+v_2,2v_1 \rangle$, $|A:B|=2$, but $n_1=n_2=2$.